# On boot, I get this error message: "Input signal out of range: change to 1920x1080@60Hz"

Tags: linux, boot, kali-linux

I am trying to install kali linux on my PC to use for a cybersecurity course I'm taking to pentest various things and learn how black hat hackers would do things and how to prevent those same mathods. Whenever I boot the linux machine up, my screen goes black except for a popup (from my monitor, not linux) that says "Input signal out of range: change to 1920x1080@60Hz". I have found various solutions online, but none of them have worked.

If it helps, here are my PC specs & monitor:

> Monitor: Lenovo 23" 1920x1080 monitor @60Hz, connected with HDMI
>   CPU: i7 6700k @ 4 GHz
>   GPU: GTX 1070 FE 8GB
>   RAM: G.Skill Ripjaws V series 16GB (2x8GB)
>   Storage: 1TB Seagate barracuda, 512GB Transcend TS SSD.

If anyone could help me out, that would be great.

I am very new to Linux, so act as if I don't know anything and please don't reference anything without providing a link or explaining.
Thanks so much!

Comment: `Any boot options for advanced install?  Then look for example of string to type to specify any matching VGA resolution with installer

Comment: @TonyStewart I use HDMI to connect, so would it still be VGA settings? Also where would I go for advanced installation settings? I didn't see any option for that...

Comment: That i7 has iGPU, is the machine defaulting to the iGPU? Is there an HDMI connector on the motherboard?

Comment: @Yorik No, the HDMI plugged into the GPU.

Comment: Normally when booting from a live Linux or install CD, you get some options in command line or function keys.  it seems your monitor does not support 1080p which seems to be default.

Comment: @TonyStewart uh my monitor does support 1080p... I run Windows 10 at 1080p..

Comment: is it your monitor that is saying signal is incompatible? then what are you installing exactly?  Try Mint

Comment: @TonyStewart yes it is my monitor and I'm installing Kali Linux.